# Is there a "human right" concerning the state and forcing citizens to enter contract?

Tags: human-rights, european-court-of-human-rights

If a state forces a citizen to enter a contract, e.g., become a customer of a company, does that violate some human right och human right like protocol (e.g., [ECHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Convention_on_Human_Rights))?

Compare with article 20b in UN's [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/universal-declaration-of-human-rights) that prohibits states from forcing citizens to join an "association".

For context, I am in EU/a country that has signed all (?) European human rights charters etc.

Comment: There is no ECHR right not to be required to enter into a contract specifically, so it would depend on the circumstances whether some other right is being breached. You would need to provide more details of exactly what requirement is being imposed. For example, if you are forced to enter into a work contract that could breach the prohibition on slavery. If you are forced to join a church, that could breach your right to freedom of religion. Etc.

Comment: Is it a contract or is it akin to mandatory registration, which is **not** a contract? This is unclear.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in your example?

Comment: this seems to be something like forced to join the sewer plant or buy electricity from a supplier.

Comment: @TigerGuy Are you really forced to join the sewer plant? Isn't it more that it is illegal dump waste in the street, but if you want to you can have your own sewage tank and hire someone to empty it and take care of it?

Comment: Why do 4 people vote to close but don't argue for their position?

Comment: @JBentley Let's say that you can't pay taxes to the local tax authority in cash but instead have to be customer in a bank and send the money electronically.

Comment: @d-b  yes homeowners are forced to connect to sanitary sewers

Comment: @TigerGuy Not where I live. In practice everyone does because it is the most convenient and least expensive, but people who live a bit out on the countryside have private solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you read 20.2 in the context of 20.1, "association" means e.g. trade unions.

EU societies widely accept the right of the state to force e.g. motorists to buy insurance from one of a few available providers, or home owners to buy utilities (rather than discharge sewage on their property) even if there is only one available provider. This is not very controversal.

There are more interesting cases, like a statutory education institutions requiring their students to get accounts with commercial providers, but again this is sustained.

Comment: Let's say that you can't pay taxes to the tax authority in cash but have to be customer with a bank and send the money electronically. You don't have to buy a car that needs an insurance (in fact, it's very common in Europe to not have a car) but you can't avoid paying taxes.

Comment: @d-b You may also have to buy a bike from one of the companies that makes bikes to get to the tax office, right?

Comment: @d-b, do you want an **answer** how human rights are commonly interpreted in the EU, or do you want to **argue** what they should be? The latter is off topic here.

Comment: @user253751 No. You can walk.

Comment: @o.m. I wonder if there is a human right that says that the government can't force you to enter a contract. Why did you even ask?

Comment: You probably have to buy some clothes before walking down the street to the tax office, if you don't want to be arrested for public nudity.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I don't think more examples like this help. Freedom of association is understood to be a right to join trade unions, churches, and parties, and constructing it to encompass a right not to enter contracts misses the point.